# Cruisecontrol.Net exception - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: iis-7, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

The question might seem to be an exact duplicate, but there's much more needed here. It's the same old error I'm getting:

```
There were exceptions connecting to the following servers:

Server    Url                                        Message
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local     tcp://localhost:21234/CruiseManager.rem    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:21234
```

I'm done with the usual troubleshoots -

1. My Cruisecontrol service is up and running
2. IIS is up and running
3. CCValidator.exe has validated my ccnet.config file, and the file is perfect.

So what could be the problem here? Any suggestions or other troubleshoots? Appreciate any sort of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out. I think this might add to the trouble-shooting steps of this issue. When I debugged a little deeper, I found that the [ccservice.exe.config](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Server%20Application%20Config%20File.html) file was missing in my server. Went a little more deeper to find that the file has been somehow renamed to "ccservice.exe.config.old" !! I'm not sure how this happened, but when I renamed it back to the original name, CC works like charm. :)

So another trouble-shooting step would be:

- Check the correctness of the CC server config files.

Comment: I had to start the service application (CruiseControl.NET) to get this to work. So can add this step too for troubleshooting the same error.